# Cannot read property 'emailVerified' of null - IONIC and FIREBASE

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set up the authentication method using angular and firebase.

When I registered a user, email verification is sent, and then after verification, the user is able to log on to the restricted area without any issues. However, sometimes when the user tries to log in, it gets the following message:

Cannot read property 'emailVerified' of null

Then, you hit again in the login button, and the authentication works.

I don't know if the error is happen due to this snippet:

```
get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
    }
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding ion-text-center">


  <div class="logo">
    <img src="../../assets/logo.png">
  </div>
<div class="form">
    <form>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" #email required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Password" type="Password" #password required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  <ion-button color="dark" type="submit" (click)="logIn(email, password)" expand="block">Login</ion-button>
  </form>
</div>
<ion-button fill="clear">New? Signup here</ion-button>
<!--<h6>{{email}}</h6>
<h6>{{password}}</h6>-->
</ion-content>
```

authentication-services.ts

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import auth from 'firebase/firebase-auth';
import { User } from "../shared/services/user";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthenticationService {
  userData: any;

  constructor(
    public afStore: AngularFirestore,
    public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone 
  ) {
    this.ngFireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  // Login in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.ngFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  // Register user with email/password
  RegisterUser(email, password) {
    return this.ngFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  // Email verification when new user register
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.ngFireAuth.currentUser.then(u => u.sendEmailVerification())
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['verify-email']);
    })
  }

  // Recover password
  PasswordRecover(passwordResetEmail) {
    return this.ngFireAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
    .then(() => {
      window.alert('Password reset email has been sent, please check your inbox.');
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }

  // Returns true when user is looged in
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }

  // Returns true when user's email is verified
  get isEmailVerified(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }

  // Sign in with Gmail
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  // Auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.ngFireAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        })
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }

  // Store user in localStorage
  SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afStore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }

  // Sign-out 
  SignOut() {
    return this.ngFireAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })
  }

}
```

I've used the following steps to create the login part:

https://www.positronx.io/create-ionic-login-sign-up-ui-with-angular/

Comment: How do you get the value of  `user`?

Comment: Hey Tarik, I am updating my post with further information. Thanks, buddy!